# How to use bitly framework in ios 5.0 with twitter framework?

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

I am using  Twitter framework to get tweets, mentions and more information from Twitter.
Now I want to use bitly in Twitter for shortening url's in twitter post's.

So please suggest how to use bitly in iOs 5.0 ?

Comment: If you only share image,text,url then try share kit. its easy for that kind of sharing...

Comment: have you added bitly library in your project, if you are facing any issues in adding that, then mention that in your application

Comment: when i added bitly library then twitter framework will use bitly byDefault or i want to implement bitly methods in my code with twitter class . am i right please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

The `Bitly Twitter` library allows you to easily include `Twitter sharing` in your application. It builds on top of the `iOS5 twitter integration`, but with these advantages over `Apple's TWTweetComposeViewController`

Refer [bitly_ios_sdk](https://github.com/bitly/bitly_ios_sdk) library source.

Refer [sharekit](https://github.com/ideashower/sharekit/) for sharing image,text,url in twitter which uses `Bitly`